# Use facebook id (given by android app) to connect with mysql database through php

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Can't seem to figure this one out...:
Let's say there are some facebook id's and their favourite color in my mysql-database.
I want my android app to enable users to connect with the database and change there fav color.
To accomplish this, on my app, the user logs in into facebook. I get the user ID, so that works fine.
I could communicate with the database using a PHP file: `.../color.php?id=<the-id-I-get-in-my-app>`, however, this is everything but secure. I could add `&access_token=<the-access-token-I-get-in-my-app>`,  but then I would need to check the access_token in my PHP file. This is the part where I'm stuck...

Are there other methods to do this or is this "the way to go"?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would this work exactly? Since one would still be abble change the userID on client side before sending it to the server (this is the security issue I want to avoid), right?

Comment: userID couldn't be changed by client, it's constant and unique for each user, only facebook itself can change it, but it is very rare situation, shouldn't be taken into account.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it would be possible to access and change another user's info in the database by adding the id as a get parameter : the php script will execute since the script receives an id, even if it's not the user's id.

Comment: who will change user's info from the database except from the authority people? you can put a duplicate control mechanism so nobody can add the same ID, also on the Facebook side the IDs are unique so there will be no duplicates at all

Comment: The ids are already in the database. You could see it this way: users go on their laptop to the fb app (not android app). There, they must choose a fav color. The id and color is stored in the database. User turn off their laptop and take their android phone and start the app. Through the app, they must be able to update their fav color. Only their color, connected with their fb id, not the color of other users.

Comment: you say `change another user's info in the database` in your previous post

Comment: I did. That's what I'm (securtiy-wise) concerned off: I don't think anyone would do that, the problem is anyone could do it if they wanted... Changing another one's fav color is not so bad, but off course this is just to demonstrate the problem, the actual info is much more sensitive. Thanks for your reply's!

Comment: yeah, it's nothing :)